# How to save state of Fragment that have listview

Tags: android

i use some fragment to show some list in tabbed app , however when i change position of tab, the `listviews` in fragment suddenly clear and item's removes ! how i can save state of each `listview` in each Fragments ?? please help me, thank you . here is code for my `onCreateViewof` one of the Fragments .

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    loadtoken();
    items = new ArrayList<item>();
    lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter_common adapter = new adapter_common(getContext(), items);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(R.color.asabani_cat, R.color.asheghame_cat, R.color.asanyevazi_cat);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (firstVisibleItem == 0) {
                // check if we reached the top or bottom of the list
                View v = lv.getChildAt(0);
                int offset = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getBottom();
                if (offset == 0) {

                    return;
                }
            } else if (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount == firstVisibleItem) {
                View v = lv.getChildAt(totalItemCount - 1);
                int offset = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
                final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                if (lastItem == totalItemCount) {
                    if (preLast != lastItem) {
                        preLast = lastItem;
                        f = f + 6;
                        j = 1;
                        new PostDataAsyncTask().execute();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? When a fragment is removed its content is also removed, the list inside should be populated when you show the fragment again, whats the problem with that?

Comment: if i request the content from web Every time fragment shown, app is work slowly, i wanna do this work that users don't need to get the data again !

Comment: Then just download it once and keep it for the rest of the execution, whats the problem doing that? dont you know what a Singleton pattern is?

Comment: no i'm beginner, i dont know about Singleton pattern ! please help me ...